# Transparent notification popups and closed questions headers

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

On the main site only, the headers of closed questions look transparent now:

> [image]

and so do the popups when flagging comments - but only the ones that used to have blue background, e.g. when flagging the comment as not an answer. They are actually transparent, you can see page text through them.
The ones that have pink background, e.g. when voting to delete when you have already voted, are not affected.

This is apparently because in `background-color: var(--theme-secondary-050)`, the `--theme-secondary-050` is not set. (It would appear it's not the only one that isn't set.)

Comment: Already reported and [meta-tag:status-review] on MSE: [Post notice background color seems to have gone on walkabout](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/367707/289905).

Comment: [It appears to have been fixed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZOGw.png)(?) but the color has [changed on dark mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gz8Xu.png). Not sure if that was intentional but it looks terrible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update** This has been fixed. See the linked MSE post here for more details. tl;dr It *was* a CDN caching issue that was serving the wrong file for specific locales.

---

*edit* It *is* a (CDN) caching issue. More info at the linked post on MSE. Status changed to [status-review](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/status-review).

Marking as [status-norepro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/status-norepro) to match the post on MSE [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/367720/395497). tl;dr - We think it is a caching issue and purged the cache for the suspected file cross network.

Comment: This appears to be geography related. This link: https://cdn.sstatic.net/Shared/stacks.css?v=8efb1861e515 still returns different content for different regions. The bad version is much shorter and is `x-served-by: cache-fra19172-FRA`. The good version is longer and is `x-served-by: cache-lon4268-LON`.

Comment: and what do you plan to do with the CDN cache ???